# File Input and Output in Python, stripping of space and outputting to list

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python to take 5 lines of input from a file 'var_input' and input it into a list, and then input each seperate number into the list first or second

I am just wondering what the best way would be to go about separating the space from in between each number and then appending it to the lists first or second. I am thinking about using python's split method but I am not sure about how to do this

Data in input file would look like this

```
18 24               
10 5
101 567
234 90
107 4567
```

first should contain `['18', '10', '101', '234', '107']`

second should contain `['24', '5', '567', '90', '4567']`

Here's What I have so far

```
first = []
second = []

file_input = open('var_input')
input_list = file_input.readlines()
```

Thank You So Much, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's worth noting that when working with files in Python, it is best to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `zip` and `split`:

```
with open('var_input') as file_input:
    input_list = file_input.readlines()
first, second = zip(*[l[:-1].split() for l in input_list])
```

How it works- `[l[:-1].split() for l in input_list]` is a list comprehension, which applies the `split` method to each line to make it look like:

```
[["18", "24"], ["10", "5"], ["101", "567"], ["234", "90"], ["107", "4567"]]
```

`zip` is a function that then zips multiple lists together (when given with `*`, it treats each item in the input list as a separate argument). It "zips" it by taking the first item of each list, then the second item of each list (if you had three or more items on each line you'd end up with three or more output lists). The result will look like

```
[('18', '10', '101', '234', '107'), ('24', '5', '567', '90', '4567')]
```

Comment: I would just recommend as well to use ``with open('var_input') as file_input:`` to let python handle the cleanup procedure.

Comment: @Fred: I think that's a good idea (changed), I just didn't want to confuse the OP by introducing too many changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
first = []
second = []

with open('var_input') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        temp = line.split()
        first.append(temp[0])
        second.append(temp[1])
```

This may looks stupid but it is simple and works.